# SUBTOTALS of a GROUP BY IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is the table I have.

```
TASK_CD    |  STATUS | DUE_DATE
----------------------------------
T0001      |  NW     | SYSDATE + 1
T0001      |  IP     | SYSDATE 
T0001      |  AG     | SYSDATE
T0002      |  NW     | SYSDATE - 1
T0002      |  NW     | SYSDATE - 2
T0003      |  AG     | SYSDATE + 1
```

This is the query I have right now

```
select TASK_CD, STATUS, SUM(1) TOTALS, 
SUM(CASE WHEN (TRUNC(DUE_DATE ) > SYSDATE) then 1 else 0 end) FUTURE, 
SUM(CASE WHEN (TRUNC(DUE_DATE ) = SYSDATE) then 1 else 0 end) TODAY, 
SUM(CASE WHEN (TRUNC(DUE_DATE ) < SYSDATE) then 1 else 0 end) OVERDUE, 
FROM TM_TASK GROUP BY TASK_CD, STATUS;
```

result will be

```
TASK_CD | STATUS | TOTALS | FUTURE | TODAY | OVERDUE
----------------------------------------------------
T0001   | NW     | 1      | 1      | 0     | 0
T0001   | IP     | 1      | 0      | 1     | 0
T0001   | AG     | 1      | 0      | 1     | 0
T0002   | NW     | 2      | 0      | 0     | 2
T0003   | AG     | 1      | 1      | 0     | 0
```

By removing STATUS from select and group, I get

```
TASK_CD | TOTALS | FUTURE | TODAY | OVERDUE
-----------------------------------------------
T0001   | 3      | 1      | 2     | 0
T0002   | 2      | 0      | 0     | 2
T0003   | 1      | 1      | 0     | 0
```

Is there a way to combine both and combine the results, giving me TOTALS_ALL, FUTURE_TOTALS, OVERDUE_TOTALS, TODAY_TOTALS where these are the sums when status is not considered for the GROUP BY

```
TASK_CD | STATUS | TOTALS | FUTURE | TODAY | OVERDUE| TOTALS_ALL | FUTURE_TOTAL | TODAY_TOTAL | OVERDUE_TOTAL
T0001   | NW     | 1      | 1      | 0     | 0      | 3          | 1
             | 2           | 0
T0001   | IP     | 1      | 0      | 1     | 0      | 3          | 1
             | 2           | 0
T0001   | AG     | 1      | 0      | 1     | 0      | 3          | 1
             | 2           | 0
T0002   | NW     | 2      | 0      | 0     | 2      | 2          | 0
             | 0           | 2
T0003   | AG     | 1      | 1      | 0     | 0      | 1          | 1
             | 0           | 0
```

Comment: Although it will not give you the same structure, as you've shown you expect, you could consider using `ROLLUP` (or for more complex cases `CUBE`) clause for `GROUP BY` - it is designed to calculate totals and sub-totals.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [subquery factoring clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) (more commonly called a common table expresssion) to generate your initial data set and then an analytic [`SUM()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTSQL/function.htm#TTSQL457) to aggregate

```
with initial_totals as (
select task_cd
     , status
     , count(*) as totals
     , sum(case when due_date >= trunc(sysdate) + 1 then 1 else 0 end) as future
     , sum(case when trunc(due_date) = trunc(sysdate) then 1 else 0 end) as today
     , sum(case when due_date < trunc(sysdate) then 1 else 0 end) as overdue
  from tm_task
 group by task_cd, status
       )
select task_cd
     , status
     , future
     , today
     , overdue
     , sum(future) over (partition by task_cd) as future_total
     , sum(today) over (partition by task_cd) as today_total
     , sum(overdue) over (partition by task_cd) as overdue_total
  from initial_totals
```

This is your original query (modified slightly see below) and then an analytic sum over each task code. An analytic sum is the same as an aggregate, but without putting the result against each row.

You can see this in action on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=182e63719cacc9763e3b227486222b84).

You'll note I've changed your date logic. This is because `TRUNC(DUE_DATE ) > SYSDATE` is the same as saying *when midnight today is greater than this second*. I've changed this to `due_date >= trunc(sysdate) + 1`, which is *when this second is at or after midnight tomorrow*. I've changed all the date logic in a similar manner.

Comment: It'd be beneficial to know, **why** the move of `TRUNC` can be good. For those cases, it'd also be good to show how to do the same for the current day `DUE_DATE`, not just past/future.

Comment: Hi @Hilarion; to be honest that hurts a bit. You're criticising the correct answer with the explanation rather than the incorrect (not just dates the SQL logic too) without an explanation. I have explained **why** moving `TRUNC()` is good as well as I know how. I haven't used the word "move" it's true, but it's not actually moving a function, it's a different logical construct. If you don't understand the explanation can you tell me what you don't understand so I can improve my explanation?

Comment: Thank you @Ben. My only dilemma is which is a better approach your or Gordon. I tried doing the explain plan and the cost for both queries is similar. On running them both I time it was taking is similar as well. But my local db has limited test data. I have to see how they perform with huge loads.

Comment: They're basically the same query @Sitaram, I don't think there'll be any difference with large amouns of data. Have you checked that the data returned is correct in both? Either can be modified to return the correct data but it looks like we've interpreted your question slightly different.

Comment: Yes, I was able to get the expected results...Thank you :)

Comment: @Ben: I'm sorry that you felt that way. My intention was not to suggest, that there's something wrong in what you wrote - I agree with your suggestion to change how `TRUNC` is used (I up-voted your answer). You did explain how your change is logically the same as original (gives the same result), but at the same time - if they are the same, then why change anything? I'd suggest an addition, e.g. "this will cause the function value to be calculated only once, instead of for each row". You've also left `trunc(due_date) = trunc(sysdate)`, which can be changed in similar fashion.

Answer (score 2):

You would use window functions:

```
select TASK_CD, STATUS, SUM(1) TOTALS, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN (TRUNC(DUE_DATE ) > SYSDATE) then 1 else 0 end) as FUTURE, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN (TRUNC(DUE_DATE ) = SYSDATE) then 1 else 0 end) as TODAY, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN (TRUNC(DUE_DATE ) < SYSDATE) then 1 else 0 end) as OVERDUE, 
       SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN (TRUNC(DUE_DATE ) > SYSDATE) then 1 else 0 end)) OVER (PARTITION BY status) as TOTAL_FUTURE, 
       SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN (TRUNC(DUE_DATE ) = SYSDATE) then 1 else 0 end)) OVER (PARTITION BY status) as TOTAL_TODAY, 
       SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN (TRUNC(DUE_DATE ) < SYSDATE) then 1 else 0 end)) OVER (PARTITION BY status) as TOTAL_OVERDUE
FROM TM_TASK
GROUP BY TASK_CD, STATUS;
```

Comment: Hi, I have already tried partitioning, it was giving "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function" exception

Comment: Try it as @GordonLinoff described - it should work. Maybe you've missed the double `SUM` use?

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff. Yes I missed the double sum use.